# Error Occurs While Joining Two Tables

Tags: sql, oracle11g

My table structures

```
create table dpt (
  dptno number, 
  dname varchar2(10), 
  loc varchar2(7)
)


create table emp1 (
  empno number,
  ename VARCHAR2(10),
  desigantion varchar2(10),
  mgr number,
  deptno number
)
```

result 1:

```
111 ram analyst 444 10
222 mohan   clerk   333 20
333 hari    manager 111 10
444 manju   engineer222 30
```

result2:

```
10  inventory   hyd
20  finance         bglr
30  hr          mumbai
```

Now I'm joining the two tables with the query:

```
 select empno,ename,desigantion,dname,loc from emp1 e,dpt d where d.dptno=e.dptno;
```

I'm getting this error:

```
e.dptno is invalid.
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess. Since there is no column `dptno` in the table `emp1` it should be `e.deptno`:

```
select empno,ename,desigantion,dname,loc from emp1 e,dpt d where d.dptno=e.deptno;
```

Comment: i got my answer thaq for helping me

Comment: can u tell.why u add e.deptno..there is no that kind column in my table but my desire output is getting..how

Comment: @ram: Please see the table definition from your question: `create table emp1(....,deptno number)`

Comment: ya got it thanq for helping me @valex

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo, you defined the field in emp1 as empno and not dptno so it should be:

```sql
SELECT empno, ename, desigantion, dname, loc
FROM emp1 e, dpt d
WHERE d.dptno=e.empno;
```

Comment: whill exicuting your query data will not come

Comment: What's the new output?